# Reactive form not called onsubmit

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I need to use my code to validate a required field.
This is my html code:

```
<div  [formGroup]="studenteForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(studenteForm)">
<input matInput class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name">
....
  <button mat-button type="submit" class="custom-send">Save</button>
</div>
```

in my .ts I do:

```
 public studenteForm: FormGroup;  

  this.studenteForm= formBuilder.group({
     name:[Validators.required];
            });
            
        }

....
 onSubmit(form:FormGroup){
       //the problem is here because it doesn't print console.log
        console.log(form);
      }
```

in my app .module:

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
```

The problem is that it doesn't call the `onSubmit` method and I  don't know why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Should the first `div` not be `form`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `<form>` instead of `<div>`
Try this:

```
<form [formGroup]="studenteForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(studenteForm)">
<input matInput class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name">
....
  <button mat-button type="submit" class="custom-send">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should wrap forms in a form tag and not in a div. Then I would do the submitting like the following. Just change your code of the HTML file:

```
<form [formGroup]="studenteForm">
    <input matInput class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name" />
    ...
    <button mat-button class="custom-send" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</button>
</form>
```

And then you don´t need the parameter of the submit method in the TS file anymore. To log the current value, you explicity have to log the `value` property , not the form itself:

```
public onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.studenteForm.value);
}
```